# mysql query using where clause with 24 million rows

Tags: mysql

```
 SELECT DISTINCT `Stock`.`ProductNumber`,`Stock`.`Description`,`TComponent_Status`.`component`, `TComponent_Status`.`certificate`,`TComponent_Status`.`status`,`TComponent_Status`.`date_created` 
FROM Stock , TBOM , TComponent_Status
WHERE  `TBOM`.`Component` = `TComponent_Status`.`component` 
AND `Stock`.`ProductNumber` = `TBOM`.`Product`
```

Basically table TBOM HAS :

24,588,820 rows

The query is ridiculously slow, i'm not too sure what i can do to make it better. I have indexed all the other tables in the query but TBOM has a few duplicates in the columns so i can't even run that command. I'm a little baffled.

Comment: Duplicates don't prevent indexing, they just prevent a certain type of index

Comment: What spec machine are you running on? What length of time is "ridiculously slow"? Please edit more detail into your question, thanks.

Comment: Yea, definitely put a non-unique index on `TBOM.Component`

Comment: Is there scope to partition your data? Or can you build a denormalised snapshot for your slowest queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start, index the following fields:

```
TBOM.Component
TBOM.Product 
TComponent_Status.component   
Stock.ProductNumber
```

Not all of the above indexes may be necessary (e.g., the last two), but it is a good start.

Also, remove the `DISTINCT` if you don't absolutely need it.

Comment: I took your tip and ran indexes, the original time  was around 6 mins, its now dropped to 1.48mins. Unfortunately the table is imported from an sql server via a flat file to my mysql server everymorning. The sql server is managed by another company so i cant really change any of the table structure to optimise. Unless you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can really think of is having an index on your Stock table on

```
(ProductNumber, Description)
```

This can help in two ways.  Since you are only using those two fields in the query, the engine wont be required to go to the full data row of each stock record since both parts are in the index, it can use that.  Additionally, you are doing DISTINCT, so having the index available to help optimize the DISTINCTness, should also help.

Now, the other issue for time.  Since you are doing a distinct from stock to product to product status, you are asking for all 24 million TBOM items (assume bill of materials), and each BOM component could have multiple status created, you are getting every BOM for EVERY component changed.

If what you are really looking for is something like the most recent change of any component item, you might want to do it in reverse...  Something like...

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      Stock.ProductNumber,
      Stock.Description,
      JustThese.component, 
      JustThese.certificate,
      JustThese.`status`,
      JustThese.date_created 
   FROM 
      ( select DISTINCT 
               TCS.Component,
               TCS.Certificate,
               TCS.`staus`,
               TCS.date_created
            from
               TComponent_Status TCS
            where
               TCS.date_created >= 'some date you want to limit based upon' ) as JustThese
         JOIN TBOM
            on JustThese.Component = TBOM.Component
            JOIN Stock
               on TBOM.Product = Stock.Product
```

If this is a case, I would ensure an index on the component status table, something like
( date_created, component, certificate, status, date_created ) as the index.  This way, the WHERE clause would be optimized, and distinct would be too since pieces already part of the index.

But, how you currently have it, if you have 10 TBOM entries for a single "component", and that component has 100 changes, you now have 10 * 100 or 1,000 entries in your result set.  Take this and span 24 million, and its definitely not going to look good.